# Testing best practice: For CRUD api

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Similar questions have been answered before, but they didn't solve my problem.

I am testing an api with create, read, update and delete methods. It is considered best to test each function separately. But,

To test create, I need to read. 
To test read, I need to create.
To test update, I need to create and read. 
To test delete. I need to create!

I have no other (for example, lower layer api) mechanism of verifying other than this api itself.

In this case, should I write one long test with everything? Or 4 different tests; each with special setup and teardown logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very subjective but I would write four different tests as it would

- be easier to maintain
- be easier to locate a possible error
- improve readability

**Readability**

What would you name your testmethod if it tests everything? I find it easier to read testmethods in a form of `CreateShouldCreateARecord` instead of  `TestCRUD`

**Locate an error**

With readability improved, it is easier to know what went wrong. Again, for one monolithic method, all you get in a report is that the `TestCRUD` method failed and you will have to drill down to find that it was a wrong implemented read.

Comment: I do not like lot more code; due to more complex setup * 4 and teardown logic * 4. But it seems that this is the price for nailing down the exact issue. E.g., if testRead fails then I should know that the setup failed (i.e., write failed) or read failed.

Comment: @AsadIqbal - As with everything, there's always a trade-off involved. In this case and my personal preference, it is worth it.

Comment: I would disagree with the part about locating the error. If we remember about the OP problem, when i see the test CreateShouldCreateARecord fail, how do I know, if it was the creating the record at fault, or maybe just the read failed and gave me a false negative? I end up looking at the code of BOTH functions and debugging. If so, I gain nothing, while i have to write more setups, teardowns etc.

Comment: @K.L. - You have a point about `Create/Read`. This shouldn't be done in two different named but otherwise identical testcases. It reduces the amount of testcases from four to three but the *intent* of trying to write a testcase for each method remains.